# Get nodes before, between and after tokens which are not tags

Tags: xpath

Is there a way using xPath to get the span nodes:

- before "token_1"
- between "token_1" and "token_2"
- after "token_2"

```
<td>
    <span class="user0">User 0</span>
    <span class="user1">User 1</span> token_1
    <span class="user2">User 2</span>
    <span class="user3">User 3</span> token_2
    <span class="user4">User 4</span>
</td>
```

The number of `span`s between each token is variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `span` elements before the text node containing `token_1` are its `preceding-sibling::span` elements so `td/text()[contains(., 'token_1')]/preceding-sibling::span` is a solution for that part; the ones following the text node containing `token_2` are its `following-sibling::span` elements so `td/text()[contains(., 'token_2')]/following-sibling::span` is solution to that other part.

For the `span`s in between, in XPath 2 e.g. `td/span[. >> ../text()[contains(., 'token_1')] and . << ../text()[contains(., 'token_2')]]`.

In XPath 1, it is a bit convoluted:

```
td/span[preceding-sibling::text()[normalize-space()][1][contains(., 'token_1')] and following-sibling::text()[normalize-space()][1][contains(., 'token_2')]]
```

Comment: For the spans in between, in XPath 2, `intersect()` should also work, right?

Comment: @JackFleeting, yes, using the intersect operator is another option.